# How to assign string a char array that starts from the middle of the array?

Tags: c++, c

For example in the following code:

```
char name[20] = "James Johnson";
```

And I want to assign all the character starting after the  white space to the end of the char array, so basically the string is like the following: (not initialize it but just show the idea)

```
string s = "Johnson";
```

Therefore, essentially, the string will only accept the last name. How can I do this?

Comment: C or C++ ? Please choose one language .

Comment: Assuming C: check out [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).  But regardless of which language it is - you're going to want to add a whole bunch of validation code (because users are dumb and enter the darndest things ;) )

Comment: Assume C++ cause of _`string`_

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem statement is.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many questions with answers about tokenizing strings on SO.

Comment: what happens if I type in 2 spaces, if I have a middle name? you need to parse strings before your program starts to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want like this..

```
string s="";
for(int i=strlen(name)-1;i>=0;i--)
{
 if(name[i]==' ')break;
else s+=name[i];
}
reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
```

Need to

```
include<algorithm>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always more than one way to do it - it depends on exactly what you're asking.

You could either:

- search for the position of the first space, and then point a char* at one-past-that position (look up strchr in <cstring>)
- split the string into a list of sub-strings, where your split character is a space (look up strtok or boost split)

Answer (score 0):

[`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) has a whole arsenal of functions for string manipulation, and I recommend you use those.

You can find the first whitespace character using [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/), and split the string from there:

```
char name[20] = "James Johnson";
// Convert whole name to string
std::string wholeName(name);
// Create a new string from the whole name starting from one character past the first whitespace
std::string lastName(wholeName, wholeName.find_first_of(' ') + 1);
std::cout << lastName << std::endl;
```

If you're worried about multiple names, you can also use [`std::string::find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)

If you're worried about the names not being separated by a space, you could use [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) and search for letters of the alphabet. The example given in the link is:

```
std::string str ("look for non-alphabetic characters...");
std::size_t found = str.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ");
if (found!=std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "The first non-alphabetic character is " << str[found];
    std::cout << " at position " << found << '\n';
}
```